# Exception-"network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-spark

I have tried running the Spark application for integration of Hbase and ES. I have tried creating the index in ES and storing the data from HBase, but received an issue “ the user is unauthorized or access denied” when connecting to ES server.

I have checked with the Operations team and bounced the ES server, have  attempted running the application and got the attached exception-**Exception in thread "main" org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalArgumentException: Cannot detect ES version - typically this happens if the network/Elasticsearch cluster is not accessible or when targeting a WAN/Cloud instance without the proper setting 'es.nodes.wan.only'**
    at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.InitializationUtils.discoverEsVersion(InitializationUtils.java:327)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.doSaveToEs(EsSpark.scala:103)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:79)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsSpark$.saveToEs(EsSpark.scala:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.spark.package$SparkRDDFunctions.saveToEs(package.scala:55)

I'm using Elasticsearch 6.1.1 v.Please let me know if anyone faced this issue and cleared the exception

Answer (score 0):

When loading data into Elasticsearch using a Spark application, you may encounter authentication issues as Elasticsearch version 6.x and above uses SSL Certificates for authentication. To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

**Pre-Requisites:**

1. Generate ***JKS*** File
2. Generate ***PEM*** file

**Resolution steps:**

1. Generate SSL Certificates using the command below:

```bash
 keytool -keystore <jks-file> -import -file <pem-file>
```

2. Validate if the certificates are generated using the following command:

```bash
 keytool -list -v -keystore <jks-file>
```

3. Provide the SSL certificate path using the Spark parameter ***driver-java-options*** as follows:

```bash
--driver-java-options="-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<jks-file-location> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=<trust-store-pwd"
```

By following these steps, your Spark application can successfully authenticate with the Elasticsearch cluster for data loading.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks all for trying this issue, I have identified the issue. It may be helpful for you if you faced the similar issue.

The issue is we are overwriting the spark default configuration in mapr - **/opt/mapr/spark/spark-2.1.0/conf**

and the spark configuration we are passing in our application were not able to bind to sparkConfig. So it is pointing to  local host during index creation(127.0.0.1:9200)- **check in your exception log if you faced this**

I have changed the configuration details in the application and passed those while creating the sparkSession object and I have tested the application.

Now, the application is working fine and I’m able to create the index in Elastic Search and load the data.

sparkConfig passed while creating the sparkSession:

**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
  .set("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
  .set("spark.es.index.auto.create", "true")
  .set("spark.es.nodes", "yourESaddress")
  .set("spark.es.port", "9200")
  .set("spark.es.net.http.auth.user","*******")
  .set("spark.es.net.http.auth.pass", "*******")
 .set("spark.es.resource", indexName)
  .set("spark.es.nodes.wan.only", "true")
val sparkSession = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).appName("sourcedashboard").getOrCreate()
```

**

Thankyou..